# Post on google plus from ios

Tags: ios, google-plus

My app has a feature to share on google plus.
My app cannot allow users to login using google.
Is it possible to post on google plus without using google plus sign in ?

Comment: No. They will need to be signed in to post on Google plus. Imagine if every website you visit was able to post in your name

Answer (score 0):

Google APIs use `OAuth 2.0` for both authentication and authorization. You cannot do anything if you are not authorized - it's the matter of security. Here is [a great official guide](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) on how to properly login in Google Plus and use different APIs features.

So, you must enable the possibility to login through Google or disable the sharing feature.